# Symetric equations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

if i have the equation :
$1-2\cos(b\ln2)×2^{1-a}+2^{2-2a}=1-2\cos(b\ln2)×2^a+2^{2a}$ does this impliy $ 2^{1-a}=2^a$?

I have tried a lot with this question so I want to know that if we have any equation of the form:

---

- **Heading**

$$xy+x^2=zy+z^2$$ then

1. List item

$x=z$;

Comment: The first part is too hard to read for me. the second part ha the solution x=z but also the solution x=-z-y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you equation is correct, then you have that

$$1-2\cos(b\ln2)×2^{1-a}+2^{2-2a}=1-2\cos(b\ln2)×2^a+2^{2a}$$
$$2^{2-2a}-2^{2a}=2\cos(b\ln2)(2^{1-a}-2^a)$$
$$(2^{1-a}-2^{a})(2^{1-a}+2^{a})=2\cos(b\ln2)(2^{1-a}-2^a)$$

What happen when $a=1/2$?

Otherwise, we have

$$2^{1-a}+2^{a}=2\cos(b\ln2)$$
$$2^{-a}+2^{a-1}=\cos(b\ln2)$$

Comment: Do you mean the equation has an error

Comment: this equation comes from the following equation:  |1-2^s|=|1-2^(1-s)|    where s=a+bi